# CFNetwork unexpectedly closes http connection

Tags: ios, core-foundation, cfnetwork

I am facing strange issue with `CFNetwork` on iOS simulator and on iOS device.

I am sending HTTP requests to remote server. Sometimes, everything works correctly. But sometimes `CFNetwork` opens a socket to remote server, sends http request in one packet and then it sends FIN packet immediately (after about 1ms).

I don't see this issue on Mac OS X, where I run similar code.

Stream is created with `CFReadStreamCreateForStreamedHTTPRequest()` and it is put to `CFRunLoop`. If this issue occurs, then run-loop reports `kCFStreamEventOpenCompleted` and subsequently it reports `kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred` with ENOTCONN as an error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my code behaves much more stable if I call:

```
CFWriteStreamSetClient(stream, kCFStreamEventNone, NULL, NULL);
```

before:

```
CFWriteStreamUnscheduleFromRunLoop(stream, ...);
```

It seems that setting of empty client before stream is unscheduled resolved all my hardly to explain issues with CFNetwork. Maybe streams are generating some events even after they should be cleaned up.